# I can't set cookies in php

Tags: php, cookies

Right then, I seem to have misunderstood something about cookies. Why doesn't this work...

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE["stop"])){
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["stop"] . "!<br />";
}


$passedvar = $_POST["stopsaway"];

if (isset($passedvar)){
echo "HHHYES!!!";
if (is_numeric($passedvar)){
echo "Yup its a number string alright! I'll turn it into a int and I'll make a cookie.";
//$passedvar = (int)$passedvar;
setcookie("stop", $passedvar, time()+30);
echo "COOKIE MADE.";
}
}

if (isset($_COOKIE["stop"])){
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["stop"] . "!<br />";
}
//var_dump($_POST["stopsaway"]);

?>
```

SECOND CODE

```
<?php

$thing = 1;

if ($thing==1){
setcookie("stop","4",time()+30);
}

if (isset($_COOKIE["stop"])){
echo "So why won't it work THERE!?";
}

print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Basically, I want the user to enter a number into a field, and then a cookie is set to that number, and the main page reflects that change. This worked ONCE. The bottom code seems to work, but for some reason it doesn't work unless I manually type in the url to go to the main page using the cookie page window. If I have the two tabs open next to eachother...it doesn't do anything just to refresh the main page after creating the cookie....I wonder why.

Also, I remember hearing that nothing can come before setcookie, for it to work it has to be the very first line of code.....  So then how am I supposed to check the input first, or other conditionals?  Thanks!  Oh right, and I'm using Firefox, but I've tested on my Android as well. And it's working on one page but not another so I don't think it's the browser.

Comment: I think the problem is that `+30` it is a tiny time if I remember correctly that 30 means 30 millisecond...make it like 3000 for 3 seconds

Comment: `I remember hearing that nothing can come before setcookie, for it to work it has to be the very first line of code..... So then how am I supposed to check the input first, or other conditionals?` You just can't output anything before it, as it triggers headers being sent. You can still have all the PHP code you like.

Comment: So I could keep the conditionals as long as they don't use echo or something? I deleted the echos, seems to do the trick. Thanks!!  And Sean no it's using seconds.

Comment: Doesn't work meaning it didn't show any proof at all of being set, or working on another page without being redirected there.  OH one more thing, kinda important. I'd like to have a header redirect on that page, is that possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_COOKIE won't be set until the next pageview. Since your cookie is set to expire after 30 seconds, chances are it's gone by the next time you access the page.

Comment: Thanks, do cookies take into account loading time??

Comment: Cookies expire exactly at the time you specified - loading time has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I see. Well I see that by default, cookies seem to use an offset of time() to determine their expiration. I'm wondering is there any way that you can set it to use a specific time that's on the page it's redirected to...as a way of saying 5 seconds after the page loads.  Also after some more dabbling and it not being 3am, I figured out what was wrong. Header redirect goes after the cookie setting, and the cookie was coming after a echo. I think I understand now that cookies can have as much PHP before then, of any type needed, as long as the code has nothing to do with writing to the page.